# Vagrant: unable to change directory user:group

Tags: cakephp, ubuntu, vagrant, file-permissions

I have set up Vagrant (ubuntu/trusty64) on Mac and it's working perfectly except the fact I just cannot change directory permissions.

I have CakePHP project running in `/var/www/[projectName]` which is also the default www-directory.

Now, CakePHP cache engine needs access to `/var/www/[projectname]/app/tmp/cache` but the user:group is set to vagrant:vagrant. I try to change it with `sudo chown -R vagrant:www-data [path]` but it just doesn't change. It always stays as `vagrant - vagrant` when I need it to be `vagrant - www-data`.
Chmod works (setting for example from 775 to 777).

Any ideas why I cannot change permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [synced folders](http://docs.vagrantup.com/v2/synced-folders/basic_usage.html)

```
config.vm.synced_folder ".", "/var/www", 
    owner: "vagrant", 
    group: "www-data", 
    mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=777"]
```

[Here](http://jeremykendall.net/2013/08/09/vagrant-synced-folders-permissions/) there a good example

Comment: Thanks, but I've tried this already. With or without synced folders, when I go to `vagrant ssh` and naviage to www-root and do `ls -l`, it shows every file and every directory still with owners `vagrant vagrant`. It should change to `vagrant www-data` as far as I'm concerned.

Every time I try to put group as `www-data`, CakePHP still gives an error telling cannot modify cache. bootstrap.php and cache engine is correct.